# Chrome caches select menu

Tags: html, google-chrome, caching, html-select

I have a select menu.
Example:

```
<select autocomplete="off"> <option value="" selected="selected">Select Quantity</option>
<option value="6" autocomplete="off">6</option>
<option value="12" autocomplete="off">12</option>
<option value="18" autocomplete="off">18</option>
<option value="24" autocomplete="off">24</option>
</select>
```

If the user selects a value and then navigates to a different page and back...the browser caches the selected value (even though I have switched off caching in the cache related headers).

How can I prevent Chrome from caching these select values?

Answer (score 6):

Add autocomplete="off" to the form (not the select element):

```
<form autocomplete="off">
<select> <option value="" selected="selected">Select Quantity</option>
<option value="6" autocomplete="off">6</option>
<option value="12" autocomplete="off">12</option>
<option value="18" autocomplete="off">18</option>
<option value="24" autocomplete="off">24</option>
</select>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you!! Thank you!!  Been researching a similar bug for 5 hours... then I found this.  Wow, can't believe this too so long to find.  This issue also occurs in IE.